# Blender crashes on launch

Tags: command-line

Have been using blender for months now and recently upgraded to the newest version 2.75a. It worked for about 2 days fine but now when i launch it the console flashes and immediately closes and blender doesn't open...

This is incredibly annoying, i have even uninstalled and reinstalled but the same thing happens.

Does anyone have a solution?

Edit: i saw those answers.... none of them work. i dont have a config file at C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.xx\config

so i cant delete startup.blend or userpref.blend

Comment: How did you install blender? (installer or zip?) Have you checked the [system path](http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/installing_blender/directorylayout.html#windows) to see if the config files are there?

Comment: I installed by installer and i have checked my system path and i cant find config

Comment: Hm... I am running the same version but running under the .ZIP instead. I had the exact issue but mines was from a missing file (can't be exact of the file name). I just went and removed anything blender related. Wiped all my python files. Cleaned bugs/viruses. Then reinstalled but this time under a .ZIP as I said above and it works. Could also be a bug that you can report to. I recommend to report your bug to https://developer.blender.org/. It's a hub where Developers of Blender help fix bugs as well as addons. Do be very descriptive, i advise pictures or videos.

Comment: if you can't find startup.blend or userpref.blend then you have problems, they should be there somewhere (most probably inside the folder where you uncompressed blender)

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling blender with a previous version? That might work and you'll just have to wait until they fix it to use 2.75.